# Resolving the response from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: json, powershell, rest, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm a bit stuck, so basically I did a call to graph `api/resources/plannertaskdetails`

```
$apiUrl = $('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/' + $taskId +'/details')
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get
```

and I got response, something like this:

```
@{@odata.context=xxxx/details/$entity; description=value 1; previewType=automatic; id=bxxxxm; references=; checklist=}
```

references and checklist are lists (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertaskdetails?view=graph-rest-1.0)

So when I do $response.checklist, I see @{18907=; 35669=; 41911=} (which represent the list items)

So when I do for example `$response.checklist.18907` 
I see  `@{@odata.type=#microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem; isChecked=True; title=Step 1; orderHint=; lastModifiedDateTime=; lastModifiedBy=}`

Now my question is, how can I easily access those list objects inside it.

To do something like

```
foreach($option in $response.checklist)
{
    $option.Title= ....;
}
```

In this $response, I can get for example description `($response.discription or $description.id)` but the checklist and reference not.

Else I'm a bit stuck, if I try to | ConvertFrom-Json, I get an error Invalid JSON primitive, etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
foreach($checklistId in $response.checklist.Keys)
{
    $response.checklist[$checklistId].title= ....;
}
```

AFAIK, Invoke-WebRequest returns a parses dictionary structure in PowerShell by parsing the JSON output.